# Can't get Django to render template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to get my view to render my HTML through a POST request from javascript but I can't make it work using the onclick="" function of an  tag?  I'm struggling to find an answer as I'm not sure how to pose the question so I will just try to show....

My view looks like:

```
def photos(request):
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    workingDir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main', 'static', 'gallery', 'img')

    vehicle = request.POST.get('car')  # Assigns the 'pass_vehicle' JS function returned value to 'vehicle' variable
    print(request)  # Debug

    number_of_images = len(os.listdir(f'{workingDir}/{vehicle}/')) - 1  # Retrieve number of images within folder for <p> tag

    cols = [(3, 6, 3), (8, 4), (6, 6), (4, 8)]  # CSS columns used below for displaying images in specific layout on HTML page

    htmlText = []
    imgNum = 0
    while imgNum <= 25:  # During development limit number of pictures to display (will have specific amount in deployment)
        for colNum in cols:
            for x in range(len(colNum)):  # Generate HTML to display each image within folder within the CSS column layout above
                imgNum += 1
                inputText = f'<div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-{colNum[x]}" data-aos="fade-up">\n  <a href="/main/static/gallery/img/{vehicle}/img_{imgNum}.jpg" class="d-block photo-item" data-fancybox="gallery">\n  <img src="/main/static/gallery/img/{vehicle}/img_{imgNum}.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">\n  <div class="photo-text-more">\n  <span class="icon icon-search"></span>\n</div>\n</a>\n</div>'
                htmlText.append(inputText)

    context = {
        'htmlText': htmlText  # This returns the correct HTML and displays correctly IF 'href={% url 'photos' %}' in 'gallery.html'
    }

    ## DIDN'T WORK EITHER
    # t = loader.get_template('main/photos.html')
    # return HttpResponse(t.render(context, request))

    ## This doesn't change the webpage but does console print the correct 'Debug'!
    return render(request, 'main/photos.html', context)
```

whilst the HTML and JS are:

```
{% for entry in titleDict %}
          <div class="pd-top col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4" data-aos="fade-up">
            <a id="{{ entry.filename }}" href="#" class="d-block photo-item" onclick="pass_vehicle(this)"> <!--As 'id' is dynamic using JS to obtain id and forward to view -->
              <img src="/main/static/gallery/img/{{ entry.filename }}/img_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="photo-text-more">
                  <div class="photo-text-more">
                    <h3 class="heading">{{ entry.vehicle }}</h3>
                  <span class="meta">{{ entry.numOfPictures }} Pictures</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

and...

```
function pass_vehicle(tag){
    $.ajax({
      url: "photos",
      type: "POST",
      data :{ 'car' : tag.id },
      success: callback
    });
}

function callback(response) {
    console.log(response)
}
```

The reason I am doing it like this is so that the gallery page updates dynamically from a folder an I can add new folder/images over time with the same naming conventions and the webpage should update automatically.

This all works perfect in the sense that it returns the photos from the correct directory and fills the HTML code correctly but it won't load the photos.html page unless I change 'href={% url 'photos' %}' within the  tag but then the POST data won't get sent?!  I have tried several return methods such as HttpResponse or redirect but I must have my configuration wrong.

If anyone can understand the question and point me in the right direction that would be a great help!?

Comment: Can you update to include your `TEMPLATES` settings?

Comment: my settings.py templates settings are 'TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
'

Comment: if you meant the urls ... urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.home, name='home'),
 path('services', views.services, name='services'),
 path('about', views.about, name='about'),
 path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
 path('gallery', views.gallery, name='gallery'), # Relevant
 path('photos', views.photos, name='photos'), # Relevant
]